# Bootstrap Stacked Navigation Bar is Stretching Images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap stacked navigation bar to display fixed sized images (as items).

From some reason the images are being stretched. Do you know how can I avoid this image stretching? can you recommend a CSS solution?

by the way, I already tried to enforce the width & height in the img tag although it did not work.

Here is part of the code:

```
 <div class="col-md-1" style="height:100%; padding:2px 0 2px 2px;">
        <div class="top-panel" style="width:100%; padding:5px;">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li style="border-radius:0px;">
                    <a style="padding:5px;" href="" popover="Service Catalog" popover-trigger="mouseenter"
                       popover-placement="right">
                        <img  ng-click="setPage('serviceCatalog')" width=61 height=61
                             ng-src="{{currentPage=='serviceCatalog' && 'resources/images/icon_catalog_active.png' || 'resources/images/icon_catalog.png'}}"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <a style="padding:5px;" href="" popover="Approver's Summary" popover-trigger="mouseenter"
                       popover-placement="right">
                        <img  ng-click="setPage('approversSummary')" width=61 height=61
                             ng-src="{{currentPage=='approversSummary' && 'resources/images/icon_approval_active.png' || 'resources/images/icon_approval.png'}}"/>
                    </a>
                </li>


            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a temporary solution which seems to solve the issue on every resolution I tested.

I noticed that the images get stretched to 71px/71px (although they are 61px/61px)
So I changed the image canvas (using GIMP) to be 71px/71px while the real image is placed inside using its original size of 61px/61px.

So, the actual stretching does not affect the image visibility.

I would prefer to use a CSS solution instead of this bypass.